# Drawing Feynman Diagrams with feynMP

Tags: feynmf

I'm trying to draw the higgs decay to two gluon diagram

[image: higgs to two gluon]

but I want gluons to go straight right and take top quark label in the middle of the loop on the line. my script is as follows:

```
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{fmffile}{h_gg}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,150)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{o1,o2}

\fmflabel{$h$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$g$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$g$}{o2}

\fmf{dashes_arrow}{i1,v1}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$}{v1,v2}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$}{v2,v3}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$}{v3,v1}
\fmf{gluon}{v2,o1}
\fmf{gluon}{v3,o2}
\fmf{phantom}{o1,o2}
\fmfdot{v1,v2,v3}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Please note that the big dot is just because of me its nothing to do with latex. Also is there a possibility that I can change the angle between outputs in a LO decay diagram, for instance, higgs to bbbar which can be;

```
\begin{fmffile}{two_body}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(70,70)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$h$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$b,c,\tau$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$\bar{b} ,\bar{b} ,\bar{\tau}$}{o2}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{i1,v1}
\fmf{quark}{v1,o1}
\fmf{quark}{v1,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please move the second part to a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add some dummy nodes on the right so that `o1` and `o2` are nearer the middle, then freeze the automatic layout with `fmffreeze` and finally push `v2` and `v3` apart with `fmfshift`.  Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{h_gg}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,150)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{d1,d2,o1,o2,d3,d4}
\fmflabel{$h$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$g$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$g$}{o2}
\fmf{dashes_arrow,tension=2}{i1,v1}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$,label.side=right}{v1,v2}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$}{v2,v3}
\fmf{quark,label=$t$}{v3,v1}
\fmf{gluon}{v2,o1}
\fmf{gluon}{v3,o2}
\fmfdot{v1,v2,v3}
\fmffreeze
\fmfshift{11down}{v2}
\fmfshift{11up}{v3}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image: Feynman diagram]

Notice I've added a couple of other small tweaks to make it a bit neater.  Adding `tension=2` to the dashed arrow makes it balance the two gluons better.  And I've pushed one of the quark labels to the other side of the arrow.

Comment: this puts t labels inside the loops is there any chance that I can take the labels out?

Comment: run it twice, so that the labels get re-positioned as in my diagram

Comment: yes I did but different numbers for up and down or for \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,150) changes the places of the labels is there any function to fix them?

Comment: @jackaraz run it twice after making changes...